# Xamarin studio : Autocomplete doesn't work in shared project

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, mono, xamarin-studio

I have a big problem with my cross-platform project using Xamarin Studio.
In my solution, I have 3 projects:

- iOS project
- Android project
- Core project (for model, data, ...)

The auto-complete works perfectly fine in the 2 firsts, but it doesn't in the third one.

Anyone have an idea why? I'm on macOS Sierra.

Thanks,
Philip

Comment: Are the `.cs` files in the `.shproj` getting syntax highlighted? I'm currently running XS Version 6.1.2 (build 44) and do not have any issues with my shared projects, in terms of code competition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already found the solution to my problem.

I forgot to reference the Core project in the iOS project and the Android project.

Philip